# Redirect with htaccess to other domain when original url finishes in determinate word

Tags: .htaccess, seo, friendly-url, http-redirect

I have a web with 3 domains. com, .de, .co.uk. One domain for one language.
By now the languages are in .com and it runs like this:

```
www.domain.com/?lang=de
www.domain.com/?lang=en
www.domain.com/?lang=fr
```

But now I need the web not accessible with www.domain.com/?lang=en and automaticaly redirect to www.domain.co.uk

I've tryed with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch de$ http://www.domain.de
```

But don't works for me. 
Anyone knows how can I do this?

Thank you very match in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `QUERY_STRING` Rewrite-Condition to check for query parameters. e.g.:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=de$
RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.domain.de [R,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer!. You have understood perfectly what I need. Your code seems correct but it not works for me. I don't know why.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=de$
RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.domain.de [R,L]

Comment: I use http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to test htaccess code and it seems no work. I write very carefully about this because it's possible that I make a mistake in any step of your solution.